# Why is Visual Studio 2022 reformatting my code when I change the form design?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am working on a .NET application and lately whenever I update a form/control layout, the code in the C# file is reformatted. I understand that the designer file is modified whenever I make a change to the form, but the normal C# file with my code shouldn't be touched unless I tell it to.

For example, if I have one line of code like:

```
if(condition) doThing();
```

When I modify a control and save the designer, the code will be changed to this:

```
if(condition)

    doThing();
```

Usually I just deal with it and undo the changes after I save the designer, but it's getting kind of annoying to always have to hit undo.

I've disabled all the automatic formatting settings I could find, but it still occurs

Comment: "I've disabled all the automatic formatting settings" - maybe not. Which settings did you disable? Please list them

Comment: @ThomasWeller I've disabled pretty much every setting that includes "automatic ..." such as "automatic brace completion", "automatically format when typing" etc. And I also have "code cleanup on save" disabled

Comment: Visual Studio is right when applies that formatting. That just helps you save readability

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio performs an automatic indentation. To customize the indentation to your liking open the Options dialog and go to:

```
Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Formatting > Indentation
```